# Change text color in the inner html code to red

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "My name is Jeremy Gordon and this is my Portfolio of my work in the QCC Software Engineering Micro Credential Boot Camp.";
```

I need to change the text in the `innerHTML` to red. How can I make the text inside this string red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM Style `color` property:

```js
document.getElementById( "something" ). innerHTML = "My name is Jeremy Gordon and this is my Portfolio of my work in the QCC Software Engineering Micro Credential Boot Camp.";
document.getElementById( "something" ).style.color="red";
```

```html
<p id="something"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help.

You can learn more about the setAttribute method here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

```
  <script>
      document.getElementById("something").setAttribute("style", "color: red;");
  </script>
```